# What is a single, all-encompassing term for an amazing find?

Tags: single-word-requests

Today I bought an old cloth-bound copy of [a commentary on *the Gospel of John*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00POF8LIO) by **[Leon Morris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leon_Morris)** for $16. I'm a bit of a book-o-phile and also a little OCD, so normally would be quite keen to have a brand new hard-cover copy of a book if I could, but I wouldn't trade this for anything.

Inside it has a hand-written dedication by Morris himself to someone called "Francis", and when I looked on the first leaf, it has the name of **[Francis Foulkes](https://www.ivpress.com/cgi-ivpress/author.pl/author_id=561)** (of *St John's College*, himself a commentator).

What's a word I could use when writing about this find that would capture the awesomeness of it (but not as *street* as *awesomeness!*)?

As in: *I just made the most ___________ find!*

Comment: What's wrong with *amazing* or *awesome*? Both of which you use in your question, and both of which I would use in that situation.  But you might also try *incredible*. (One-in-a-million?  spectacular?)

Comment: @Jim They are both a bit casual for what I'm after. I really wanted something that's not exactly antiquated, but closer to that than the terms I used. Something with some weight, some gravitas, some ... *awesomeness.* LOL.

Comment: serendipitous ?

Comment: @mgb Hey, that is much more what I was after. It really fits in a lot of ways. +1

Comment: Wondrous? Bonanza? ... Hmm.

Comment: *a rare find*...

Comment: @ermanen Doesn't fit in the supplied sentence well.

Comment: I would suggest *momentous* as in "I just made the most [**momentous find**](https://www.google.it/search?q=momentous+find&oq=momentous+find&aqs=chrome..69i57.6614j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=%22momentous+find%22&tbm=bks)" but *monumental find* and *staggering find* are also good candidates, I believe. (They're up for grabs, if anyone likes any of these suggestions.)

Comment: @DanielStowers: You can say "the most rare find" actually. Here is one of the definitions of *rare* in *OED*: "Unusually good, fine, or worthy; of uncommon excellence or merit."

Answer (score 1):

The single word that comes to mind after reading your description *is* 'serendipitous'. I won't suggest that word because it's already been suggested in the comments.

Other words seem less apt, but certainly there are many. It's true, also, that best would be a word fitting the individual occasion, rather than a general, all-purpose word (such as 'serendipitous'). So, considering the nature of your particular find, this word may be best overall:

> **providential**, *adj.* and *n.*
>   A. adj.
>   1. a. Of, relating to, or ordained by divine providence.

["providential, adj. and n.". OED Online. September 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/153453?redirectedFrom=providential (accessed November 24, 2015).]

In your example, 'providential' works well:

> I just made the most *providential* find!

Other good candidates, depending on what aspect of the find you want to emphasize, include

- propitious
- adventitious
- auspicious

Of those, 'propitious' emphasizes the current circumstances at the time of the find:

> 1. presenting favorable conditions; favorable ....

[propitious. (n.d.) Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. (2010). Retrieved November 24 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/propitious ]

'Auspicious' looks forward to future circumstances:

> Adj.  1.  auspicious - auguring favorable circumstances and good luck ....

[auspicious. (n.d.) WordNet 3.0, Farlex clipart collection. (2003-2008). Retrieved November 24 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/auspicious .]

A usage note points up the distinction between 'auspicious' and 'propitious':

> auspicious, propitious - Auspicious implies success in the future, while propitious means favorable conditions are present; auspicious means promising or of good omen—not just special or memorable.

[propitious. (n.d.) Farlex Trivia Dictionary. (2011). Retrieved November 24 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/propitious .]

Last, 'adventitious' emphasizes the accidental, unexpected nature of your find:

> 1. added or appearing accidentally or unexpectedly.

[adventitious. (n.d.) Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged. (1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003). Retrieved November 24 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/adventitious .]

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest "fortuitous":

> I just made the most **fortuitous find**!

Definition:

> 1. Happening by accident or chance.
> 2. Resulting in good fortune; lucky.

([AHD](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=fortuitous))

This has the added benefit of alliteration and thus sounds more impactful, IMO.